# Enviando via POST modo diferenciado

Tags: php, html

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema, estou usando o método de pagamento do pagseguro, de forma que eu preencha os dados em um form e envio para a pagina do pagseguro, e lá na pagina eu termino o pagamento. porém preciso que essa aba externa abra no próprio site dele, "IFRAME" mas não consigo fazer com que ao clicar no botão "pagar" ele envie o conteúdo do form para a pagina do pagseguro e abra essa mesma pagina com os dados no meu site via iframe... vou explicar melhor...

Tenho aqui o form ser preenchido com variaveis...

```html
<!-- Declaração do formulário -->  
<form method="post" target="pagseguro"  
action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html">  
          
        <!-- Campos obrigatórios -->  
        <input name="receiverEmail" type="hidden" value="suporte@lojamodelo.com.br">  
        <input name="currency" type="hidden" value="BRL">  
  
        <!-- Itens do pagamento (ao menos um item é obrigatório) -->  
        <input name="itemId1" type="hidden" value="0001">  
        <input name="itemDescription1" type="hidden" value="Notebook Prata">  
        <input name="itemAmount1" type="hidden" value="24300.00">  
        <input name="itemQuantity1" type="hidden" value="1">  
        <input name="itemWeight1" type="hidden" value="1000">  
        <input name="itemId2" type="hidden" value="0002">  
        <input name="itemDescription2" type="hidden" value="Notebook Rosa">  
        <input name="itemAmount2" type="hidden" value="25600.00">  
        <input name="itemQuantity2" type="hidden" value="2">  
        <input name="itemWeight2" type="hidden" value="750">  
  
        <!-- Código de referência do pagamento no seu sistema (opcional) -->  
        <input name="reference" type="hidden" value="REF1234">  
          
        <!-- Informações de frete (opcionais) -->  
        <input name="shippingType" type="hidden" value="1">  
        <input name="shippingAddressPostalCode" type="hidden" value="01452002">  
        <input name="shippingAddressStreet" type="hidden" value="Av. Brig. Faria Lima">  
        <input name="shippingAddressNumber" type="hidden" value="1384">  
        <input name="shippingAddressComplement" type="hidden" value="5o andar">  
        <input name="shippingAddressDistrict" type="hidden" value="Jardim Paulistano">  
        <input name="shippingAddressCity" type="hidden" value="Sao Paulo">  
        <input name="shippingAddressState" type="hidden" value="SP">  
        <input name="shippingAddressCountry" type="hidden" value="BRA">  
  
        <!-- Dados do comprador (opcionais) -->  
        <input name="senderName" type="hidden" value="José Comprador">  
        <input name="senderAreaCode" type="hidden" value="11">  
        <input name="senderPhone" type="hidden" value="56273440">  
        <input name="senderEmail" type="hidden" value="comprador@uol.com.br">  
  
        <!-- submit do form (obrigatório) -->  
        <input alt="Pague com PagSeguro" name="submit"  type="image"  
src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/120x53-pagar.gif"/>  
          
</form>
```

fiz um esquema com php que antes de clicar em pagar o iframe fica desativado, porém quando eu clicar em pagar devo voltar para  mesma pagina que estou, e ativar esse iframe mandando os dados do form acima para o link que está no iframe.

```html
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html" width="400px" height="600px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Você pode utilizar o atributo target do seu form voltado para o name do seu iframe, ficaria assim:

```
<form action="url_pagseguro" method="post" target="iframe_pagseguro">
  <input type="submit" value="Do Stuff!" />
</form>

<iframe name="iframe_pagseguro"></iframe>
```

Ao enviar ele carregará os dados dentro do iframe ao invés de uma nova janela (`_blank`) ou na mesma página (`_self`)

Veja o exemplo "funcionando": https://jsfiddle.net/8uz1bt2h/

> Lembrando que você pode fazer com que o iframe apareça/suma sem
>   precisar recarregar a página, utilizando javascript.

Comment: Lembrando que você pode fazer com que o iframe apareça/suma sem precisar recarregar a página utilizando javascript

Comment: Escreve essa observação na resposta. É melhor.

Comment: Valeu, adicionei.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO! VOCÊS SAO FODA! <3

Comment: @douglasdutra aprove a resposta se ela estiver correta!